# Ionic 3 onclick percentage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to know if I have 2 buttons, `Button 1` and `Button2` and want to know the click percentage of buttons. Mean if the user press `button 1`, it must show 100% on button 1
and if another user click on `button 2`, it must show 50% on `button 1` and 50% on `button 2`.
any help please?

```
export class FrontPage {
  clickvalue1: number;
  clickvalue2: number;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController
  ) {
    this.clickvalue1 = 0;
    this.clickvalue2 = 0;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FrontPage');
  }

  Question() {
    this.navCtrl.push(QuestionPage);
  }

  click1() {
    this.clickvalue1++;
  }

  click2() {
    this.clickvalue2++;
  }
}
```

This is how I take the clickcount number

Example image [please seee this image need to show percentage like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxSge.png)

Comment: So you want to know how to calculate the percentages to show on the buttons? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: yes. like if 1 click on button 1 . it shows 100%on button1 and 0% on button2. like this and if click on button 2 time and button2 1 time it shows 75% on button1 and 25%on buttons 2 .

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxSge.png like this need to show percentage like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Sandy gave you the basic formula and the way to use that in the template using {{ }}. Now if you want to move calculation logic into ts:

// add some form of index as argument to the function:

```
<button ion-button (click)="clickedButton(1)"> Button 1, {{ clickPercentage1 }}% </button>
<button ion-button (click)="clickedButton(2)"> Button 2, {{ clickPercentage2 }}% </button>
```

// in the ts file have method clickedButton(index):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  clickvalue1: number;
  clickvalue2: number;
  clickPercentage1: number;
  clickPercentage2: number;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.clickvalue1 = 0;
    this.clickvalue2 = 0;
    this.clickPercentage1 = 0;
    this.clickPercentage2 = 0;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FrontPage');
  }

  Question() {
    this.navCtrl.push(QuestionPage);
  }

  clickedButton(index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        this.clickvalue1++;
        this.clickPercentage1 = this.clickvalue1 / (this.clickvalue1 + this.clickvalue2) * 100;
        this.clickPercentage2 = this.clickvalue2 / (this.clickvalue1 + this.clickvalue2) * 100;
        break;
      case 2:
        this.clickvalue2++;
        this.clickPercentage1 = this.clickvalue1 / (this.clickvalue1 + this.clickvalue2) * 100;
        this.clickPercentage2 = this.clickvalue2 / (this.clickvalue1 + this.clickvalue2) * 100;
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Here is working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vryoig

Comment: Thanks Brother <3

Comment: Is this possible i only get the number mean i also get the value in decimal. like 3.333333 . it show it like 3 or 4.

Comment: Sure, so you want decimals or not? In the stackblitz code in ts file you can see i used math.round method, you can remove it to get decimals

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in your html page for showing percentages of each button:

button1 percentage: `{{(clickvalue1>0)?(clickvalue1/(clickvalue1+clickvalue2))*100 : 0}}%`
button2 percentage: `{{(clickvalue2>0)?(clickvalue2/(clickvalue1+clickvalue2))*100 : 0}}%`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: not understand i want to show like this . If i click on A-button 2 time . And Click on B-button 1 time . It show percentage like Abutton percentage is 75% and B-buttons percentage is 25%.

Comment: No, I think you are not getting it. When A button is clicked 2 times and B button clicked 1 time , percentage should be 66.67% and 33.33% respectively. Please correct me if missed something.
For 75 and 25 ratio, clicked count be like 3 and 1 respectively.

Comment: sorry you are right . how can i do this any help ? because also need to save it in database

Comment: Please refer my answer.

Comment: Thanks Bro its working  . can you help  how can i get the both values from typescript  ? mean i directly calculate in html . need to calculate in typescrpt so i can adlso add in my database,